# How to mutually share values without influencing senders

Tags: cryptography

## Goal

I want Alice and Bob to communicate a message without their answers influencing each other. More formally:

- Alice wants to send Bob a message, `a`.
- Bob wants to send Alice a message, `b`.
- But Alice must not know `b` before sending `a`
- And Bob must not know `a` before sending `b`.

## Attempt

I was thinking I could have:

- Alice sends an encrypted message, `f(a, p1) = a'`, and a hash with the original message and the private key, `h(a, p1)`.
- Bob also sends an encrypted message, `f(b, p2) = b'` and hash, `h(b, p2)`.
- Alice and Bob exchange private keys once they have received their messages
- They decrypt the received messages and verify the hash matches

Is there any problems with this method? Would it be feasible for Alice to construct a `p'` that causes the message to be decrypted as something other than `a` yet still satisfy the hashing function? (assuming cryptographically secure `f` and `h`)

Are there more commonly accepted ways to do this?

Comment: You'll get better answers on crypto.se but given an appropriate f and h, that looks sensible to me

Comment: Posted on crypto as per @crovers suggestion and got a good answer there:  https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51960/how-to-mutually-share-values-without-influencing-senders